# Вывод из файла структуры С++

Tags: c++, структуры

Есть структура с информацией про игрушки, название, цена, возраст. Сначала создаем файл, а потом с него читаем. Не могу вывести названия и цены самой дешевой и дорогой игрушки. Не пойму в чем проблема. Если можно то без всяких сложностей (типа :: ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct toys {
    char name[12];
    float price;
    int min_age;
    int max_age;
} toy;

void toyin() {
        int i;
        FILE *f;
        i=1;
        if ((f=fopen("toys.dat", "wb"))==NULL) {
            printf("Error!!!\n");
            }
        do {
            printf("Toy #%i \n",i++);
            printf("Name: ");
            scanf("%s", &toy.name);
            printf("Price: ");
            scanf("%f", &toy.price);
            printf("Min age: ");
            scanf("%i", &toy.min_age);
            printf("Max age: ");
            scanf("%i", &toy.max_age);
            fwrite(&toy, sizeof(toy),1,f);
            printf("Finish? (Esc) \n");
        }
        while (getch()!=27);
        fclose(f);
    }

void toyout() {
    FILE *f;
    if ((f=fopen("toys.dat", "rb"))==NULL) {
        printf("Error!!!\n");
        }
    printf("Searched toys: ");
    while ( fread(&toy,sizeof(toy),1,f)!=0) {
        if (toy.min_age>=3 && toy.max_age<=5 && toy.price<=200) {
            printf("%s ", toy.name);
            }
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
}

void toyprice() {
    int min, max;
    string min_name;
    string max_name;
    max = 0;
    FILE *f;
    if ((f=fopen("toys.dat", "rb"))==NULL) {
        printf("Error!!!\n");
        }
    while (fread(&toy,sizeof(toy),1,f)!=0) {
        if (toy.price>max) {
            max = toy.price;
            max_name = toy.name;
            }
    }
    min = max;
    while (fread(&toy,sizeof(toy),1,f)!=0) {
        if (toy.price<min) {
            min = toy.price;
            min_name = toy.name;
            }
    }
//ТУТ ВЫДАЕТ ОШИБКУ
    printf("Min price: %s %f  Max price: %s %f \n", min_name, min, max_name, max);  
    fclose(f);

}

int main() {
char flag;
cout<<"Write file? (Y/N): ";
cin>>flag;

if (flag=='y' || flag=='Y') {
toyin();    
}
else {
    cout<<"Read file? (Y/N): ";
    cin>>flag;
    if (flag=='y' || flag=='Y') {
        toyout();
        toyprice();
    }
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- ```
  int min, max;
  string min_name;
  string max_name;
  ...
  printf("Min price: %s %f  Max price: %s %f \n", min_name, min, max_name, max);
  ```

  Формат `%s` требует C-строку в качестве аргумента, а вы ему туда `std::string` передаете. Разумеется, получится белиберда.

  Формат `%f` требует значение типа `double` в качестве аргумента, а вы ему туда `int` передаете. Разумеется, получится белиберда.
- ```
  scanf("%s", &toy.name);
  ```

  Использование оператора `&` в совокупности с форматом `%s` - практически всегда ошибка.
- ```
  while (fread(&toy,sizeof(toy),1,f)!=0) {
   ...
  }
  ...
  while (fread(&toy,sizeof(toy),1,f)!=0) {
    ...
  }
  ```

  После того, как первый цикл завершился из-за того, что `fread` не смогла больше ничего прочитать, почему вы надеетесь, что в втором цикле `fread` вдруг сможет что-то прочитать?
- Почему `toy` объявлена как *глобальная* переменная? Судя по остальному коду, вы умеете объявлять локальные переменные. В чем тогда идея с глобальной `toy`?
- Формат `%i` в функции `scanf` предназначен в первую очередь для того, чтобы дать пользователю возможность подавать на вход не только десятичную запись целочисленных значений, но и восьмеричную, и шестнадцатеричную запись: через использование принятых в С и С++ префиксов `0` или `0x`. Вы в своей программе хотели дать пользователю такую возможность? Если нет, то к чему здесь `%i`?
- Для использования типа `std::string` необходимо включение заголовка `<string>`. Где оно у вас в коде?
- Что за мешанина из ввода/вывода средствами C и ввода/вывода средствами С++?
- Что в этой программе делает `#include <string.h>` и `#include <Windows.h>`?

Comment: Да, #include <Windows.h> лишнее.
%i ну типа для integer ввод
& с %s в примере преподавателя было, <string.h> тоже. Оно то работает, запись в файл есть.
<string> не помогает.
int min/max поменял на float, char на string - ошибка осталась.

Comment: @Илья: Что там было у преподавателя - не важно. Десятичный целочисленный ввод - это `%d`, а не `%i`. Исправлять надо все ошибки, а не только некоторые. Пока все не исправите - не поможет. Самую первую вы, как я понял, так и не исправили.

Comment: И что такое "char на string"? Где это вы решили "char на string" поменять???

Comment: `void toyprice() {
 float min, max;
 char min_name[12];
 char max_name[12];
 max = 0;
 FILE *f;
 if ((f=fopen("toys.dat", "rb"))==NULL) {
  printf("Error!\n");
  }
 while (fread(&toy,sizeof(toy),1,f)!=0) {
  if (toy.price>max) {
   max = toy.price;
   max_name = toy.name;
   }
 }
 min = max;
 while (fread(&toy,sizeof(toy),1,f)!=0) {
  if (toy.price<min) {
   min = toy.price;
   min_name = toy.name;
   }
 }
 printf("Min price: %s %f  Max price: %s %f \n", min_name, min, max_name, max);
 fclose(f);
 
}`
Ну сделал так, теперь другие ошибки

Comment: Разумеется, другие ошибки. Раз уж вы взялись `std::string` на `char[12]` менять, то делайте все, что для этого требуется. `char[12]` и `std::string` - это сильно разные вещи. В вы думали, что вам нужно просто исправить объявление переменной? Так не получится.\

Comment: Однако менять `std::string` на `char[12]` было совсем не обязательно. `std::string` можно использовать с `printf`, только это надо делать правильно. (По-прежнему, однако, не ясно что это за мешанина из ввода/вывода средствами C и ввода/вывода средствами С++ и к чему она здесь.)

Comment: @Илья: вот вы на своей шкуре и убедились, что мешать в одном коде си и с++ плохая идея. Проще всего чтение вывод на с++ формат переписать.